# MSSQL query not working, even if there is data

Tags: sql-server, sql, query

Trying to run a more complex SQL query on an MS SQL server, but I get no data output. Logically should be fine, but I cant see why it doesnt work:

`SELECT D.NAME DATABASE_NAME,T.NAME TABLE_NAME,I.NAME INDEX_NAME,C.NAME COLUMN_NAME
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (NULL, NULL, NULL , NULL, 'LIMITED') XXX
INNER JOIN SYS.DATABASES D
ON D.DATABASE_ID = XXX.DATABASE_ID
INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES T
ON T.OBJECT_ID = XXX.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN SYS.INDEXES I
ON I.OBJECT_ID = T.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN SYS.INDEX_COLUMNS IC
ON IC.OBJECT_ID = I.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN SYS.COLUMNS C
ON C.OBJECT_ID = IC.OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY D.NAME, T.NAME`

If I run `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (NULL, NULL, NULL , NULL, 'LIMITED')`, I get proper data, so the other query should work, but still doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you are running this in master..  the sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats reports at global level, the other tables are at a database level.

you can confirm this by USE  and executing you *should* see data returned.
You may also want to use sp_msforeachDB  ( http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx) to execute the code in each database.